# How many files can I have on a single directory?

Tags: files, directory, system

This question is related to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25038/making-files-generally-available-on-linux-system-when-security-is-relatively-un).

I work with animation, which generates a LOT of files (+/- 1,000,000) typically stored on a single directory. On Mac Os X, some bugs came up with more than +/-30,000 files, so I used to break the animation into various directories.

On Ubuntu, is there a limit for the number of files a single directory can hold?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ubuntu does not limit the size of a directory, it's imposed by the file system. Each file and directory is an so-called inode. You can use `df -i` to check the number of inodes in use and available for all mounted filesystems.

I've just created 1 million and one files without issues because my inode limit for my ext4 home partition of 50 GB (46 GiB) is large enough.

I used shell expansion for creating the files, combined with the `touch` utility:

```
mkdir test
cd test
touch {0..300000}
touch {300000..600000}
touch {600000..900000}
touch {900000..1000000}
```

This creates 1000001 files which can be verified with `ls | wc -l`. Why `300000..600000` and not `300001..600000`? Because I was too lazy to put that 1 at the end.

`df -i` looks like:

```
/dev/sda6            3055616 1133635 1921981   38% /home
```

Now remove the test files (`cd ..&&rm -f test` took much longer, so use `rm` with the filenames):

```
rm {0..300000}
rm {300000..600000}
rm {600000..900000}
rm {900000..1000000}
cd ..
rmdir f
```

and the number of inodes in use decreased immediately after removal of the files:

```
/dev/sda6            3055616  133634 2921982    5% /home
```

Note that even if the filesystem allows such large numbers of files, it's a horrible idea to store such large files in a single directory. At least use some subdirectories with a structure like `f/i/l/e/filename.ext`. Programs do often not expect such large quantities of files.

Comment: wow. I am learning a lot from your answer, many thanks. But my programs do expect a large quantities of files (After Effects, Autodesk Combustion) and handles them as a unique file. (seqs of jpgs, tifs, pngs, dpxs, etc.. ). This should work with ext3 extension too?

Comment: `ext4` is a filesystem type, not a file extension. Can't you create a directory for queuing edits? I doubt that those programs can run nicely with such large file quantities.

Comment: Sure I can. I'm just imagining problems before I get to them. You're right about Adobe After Effects, 'll crash certainly, but don't doubt Autodesk guys, they make amazing pieces of code... =) looks like using a Ferrari. Very easy to crash, very fast and powerfull because is blocked on ground. Hope my english makes sense.

Comment: I understand it. Yay, exactly 17.000 reputation ^^

Comment: Before deleting the files, try and open this directory up in Nautilus and see what happens ;).

Comment: Let's assume that the system (for some reason) uses nearly all iNodes available... what can you do to increase it? How can I tell Ubuntu to use more iNodes for a certain EXT4-mount?

Comment: @bzero Please open a new question for that.

Comment: @Lekensteyn done: http://askubuntu.com/questions/600159/how-can-i-increase-number-of-files-in-an-ext4-partition

Comment: "This creates 1000001 files which can be verified with ls | wc -l. Why 300000..600000 and not 300001..600000? Because I was too lazy to put that 1 at the end." love the explanation that's longer than the actual change. :)