# How can I create an EXT4 partition with an extra large number of inodes?

Tags: 14.04, ext4, inode

**About inodes**

In Ubuntu, each file and directory is a so-called `inode`. You can use `df -i` to check the number of inodes in use and available for all mounted filesystems.

**Question**

If you create a new EXT4-partition, it uses the default number of inodes, which under normal conditions should be sufficient. However, if you run a system that produces millions of small files, how do you need to create a new EXT4 partition with an extra large number of inodes? What is the maximum?

**Comments**

- You can NOT change the number of available inodes AFTER the EXT4-partition has been created

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/231585/running-out-of-inodes

Comment: @Rinzwind That is not the same question as it only asks how to find the large number of small files... it does not explain how to format a new EXT4 partition with extra large number of inodes. I will reopen my question.

Comment: How can I disable that top banner saying that this question may already have been answered? This is a different question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `mkfs -t ext4 -N iNumberOfINodes /dev/XdY` where `iNumberOfINodes` is a 32-bit number so the maximum possible number of inodes on any ext2/3/4 file system is 2^32-1, or 4,294,967,295 (~4 billion).

Comment: Are there any known performance drawbacks when configuring 4,000,000,000 iNodes?

Comment: actually it's not: mkfs.ext4: too many inodes (4294967296), specify < 2^32 inodes

Comment: @dalore off-by-one error: 2^32-1...  Thanks for the feed-back, answer adapted...  **:-)**

Comment: Note I also tried that, but got another error which wasn't very informative as to what number is accepted.

Comment: have you tried 2^31???

Answer (score 4):

See the man page for mkfs.ext4.

```
man mkfs.ext4
```

Option `-N` allows you to set the number of inodes created in the filesystem, and option `-I` allows you to increase their size (so they can handle more extended attributes of files).  Adjust to fit your situation when you create the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, so -N is used at creation time whereas -l can be used to adjust the number of inodes AFTER the partition has been created? I will take a closer look at the man pages now...

Comment: The `-I` changes the size of each inode in bytes at creation time. It will not allow you to increase the available number of them on existing filesystems.

Comment: `"allows you to increase their size (so they can handle more files)"` Increasing the inode size doesn't mean you can handle more files, the larger the bytes-per-inode ratio, the fewer inodes will be created, meaning fewer files can be handled.

Answer (score 2):

It's always a trade off between inodes and block size.
32-bit is the max, but the actual max depends on your disk/filesystem size divided by block size. Each file is at minimum one block. You can also specify the group size which determines how many blocks per inode. (i.e. bytes/inode)

All that will determine the number of inodes you can allocation for a particular disk size and block size.

It's also a trade off between performance versus file capacity.
Smaller block size mean large files will be fragmented and require more I/O operations to load the file.

If you're gonna customize you need to read up or else you end up with a filesystem totally unsuitable for what you thought you wanted.