# Create a >281TB ext4 filesystem

Tags: partitioning, ext4

I have a connected a 287TB disk-array to a Ubuntu server. (Both Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS tested) and I have written a GPT and created a single partition using all diskspace:

```
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of command.
(parted) print
Model: LSI MR9286CV-8e (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 287TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start    End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB   287TB  287TB               DAS
```

However, when I try to create a ext4-filesystem, I get the following error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -T largefile4 /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: Cannot create filesystem with requested number of inodes while setting up superblock
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: Cannot create filesystem with requested number of inodes while setting up superblock
```

However, if I create a partition with a size of 281TB or less, I have no problems.

Isn't it possible to create a ext4 filesystem bigger than 281TB?

Comment: Maybe related (and this is a big big MAYBE): https://askubuntu.com/q/600159 , https://askubuntu.com/q/70351 and https://askubuntu.com/q/231585

Comment: Are you running a 32bit system?

Comment: 287... Terabytes... :O

Comment: @terdon: No, it's a 64bit system.

Comment: When you create a 281TB file system, is that with `largefile4`, or without?

Comment: Don't you want to try to create LVM partition on this storage?

Comment: @M.Dm.: Why should I create a LVM partition? I mean, what benefits will it have? I still need to create a 287TB filesystem on top of that, doesn't I?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto At 10TB/disk in RAID0, that's only 28 disks or so which can fit into a pretty standard 4RU case with a reasonably-priced RAID controller card.

Comment: @tudor, if you are going to fit that much data in RAID0, a cheaper alternative would just be dumping it to /dev/null... Things break, so there must be at least another copy.

Comment: @AndreaLazarotto There's more than one way to build redundancy. https://xkcd.com/1737/

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you are trying to create a file system on a volume which has `512B` block size.

First create a partition with `4K` block size and then try to create file system on it.

OR simply use this command.

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -T largefile4 /dev/sdb1 -b 4096
```